# Creating new blog with tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model-associations

Im trying to setup a blog with tagging, and i've run into a problem when trying to save.

I got 3 models

**blog model**

```
has_many :blog_tags
has_many :tags, :through => :blog_tags
```

**blog_tag model**

```
belongs_to :blog
belongs_to :tag
```

**tag model**

```
[nothing]
```

When i post my blog form, i got an input field with a comma seperated list of tags that i would like to create in the blog_tags tabel.

I've been trying out some different stuff and ended up with this

```
@blog_tags = params[:blog][:tags].split(",")

@blog_tags.each do |tag|
  @tag = Tag.find_by_tag(tag)
  @blog.tags.push(@tag)
end
```

Seemed to be working besides it complained that the parent wasn't created, and in the 2nd try it gave me an error for trying to split the string "string1" which i guess is caused by not having any commas.

I really hope one of you out there can help me out here, or atleast point me in the right direction :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a gem. Try https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on for example.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I prefered doing it myself because im mainly doing the web page as a learning rails project, but after thinking about it for a while i decided to go with the gem :-)

Comment: I understand your point but reinventing the wheel isn't a real benefit unless you're a real beginner. Learning to deal with code, reading the code orusing APIS written by someone else is a great way of learning anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to handle the cases where `params[:blog][:tags]` has no commas. In this case, the whole string is one tag, so just add it.

You might also need to deal with cases like "ruby, ,rails" i.e making sure the tags aren't empty.